# How to create check box from multidimensional array using angular js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array I want to print all data with check box.
there is dietry_reqs array below in the code I want to create check box with these value which value is true that will selected.
How to put dietry_reqs in ng-repeat

```
{  
   "attendance":[  
        {  
         "id":"13",
         "event_booking_id":"19",
         "seat_type":"",
         "fname":"",
         "lname":"",
         "email":"",
         "company":"",
         "dietry_reqs":[  
            {  
               "id":1,
               "name":"delhi",
               "value":false
            },
            {  
               "id":2,
               "name":"mumbai",
               "value":false
            },
            {  
               "id":3,
               "name":"ahmedabad",
               "value":false
            }
         ],
         "attend_status":"0",
         "created":"2016-05-04 11:41:28"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my code I have not written all fields code.
    I called check box like that but i am getting response as below image

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="itemse in items track by $index">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="form-group" mod="itemse">
                    <select class="form-control" name="seat_type" ng-model="itemse.seat_type">
                        <option ng-selected="selected" value="Table">Table</option>
                        <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group" mod="itemse">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="itemse.fname" focus/>
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
                <label ng-repeat="itemcheck in itemse.dietry_reqs track by $index">
                 <input type="checkbox" value="{{itemcheck.value}}">{{itemcheck.name}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not provided enough code but as far as i understand, you can do something like that:

```
   <div ng-repeat="level1 in attendance">
      <div ng-repeat="level2 in level1.dietry_reqs">
         <input type="checkbox" value="{{level2.value}}">{{level2.name}}
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I did like that but I am getting repeated check box

Comment: then please give more detail about your question because you mentioned to display all data with checkbox?

Comment: <label ng-repeat="itemcheck in items.dietry_reqs">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in itemcheck">
            {{key}} : {{value}}  </div> When I am printing this array in side the loop I am getting  "every character" is like key and value