# how to create multiple checkbox from associative array in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Hello I am Posting 3rd time my question for checkbox.
Fully code and response on this question which I have posted already.
I have created fiddle of my data. 
I am getting broken data please check my fiddle.
```

Please test my json may be there is problem. 
I want to create check box using dietry_reqs data.
        http://jsfiddle.net/ashishoft/03L3faq5/2/

```
Please please help me :(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: your dietry_reqs is a string not an iterable object:

fixed:

```
"dietry_reqs": [{"id":1,"name":"delhi","value":false},{"id":2,"name":"mumbai","value":false},{"id":3,"name":"ahmedabad","value":false}],
```

And the checkboxes:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in thing.dietry_reqs">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.value"> | {{value.name}} => {{value.value}}
</li>
```

Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/pz2f2k39/

Also: [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: May you(Anderi) fix my problem on fiddle please. I am unable to get inside value Please

Comment: You dont need the (key, value) since you are itterating over an array, just use "value in things.dietry_reqs". It's not wrong but might be confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("Demo", []);
app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
  $scope.things = {
    "attendance": [{
      "id": "14",
      "event_booking_id": "32",
      "seat_type": "",
      "fname": "",
      "lname": "",
      "email": "",
      "company": "",
      "dietry_reqs": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "delhi",
        "value": true
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "mumbai",
        "value": false
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "ahmedabad",
        "value": false
      }],
      "attend_status": "0",
      "created": "2016-05-05 11:24:56"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="a in things.attendance">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="dr in a.dietry_reqs">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dr.value" />{{ dr.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: :( there some problem in my json because I am not getting proper result still now

Comment: if you check the jsFiddle link then you'll see it's working. What json result are you talking about?

Comment: which json posted on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027289/how-to-create-check-box-from-multidimensional-array-using-angular-js